# rspec controller test expecting route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to test that on the creation of a post, the user is redirected to deployments path. I have added in

```
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

to extend rails routes to rspec. But my test still fails with the following error

```
1) Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to(path)
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/deployments/new> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/deployments/new.1473>.
   Expected "http://test.host/deployments/new" to be === "http://test.host/deployments/new.1473".
     # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Here is the test:

```
  describe "post create" do
    before do
      allow(model).to receive(:new).and_return(instance)
    end
    context "where all is not well" do
      before do
        allow(instance).to receive(:save).and_return(false)
        post :create, params_new_instance
      end
      sets_flash(:error)
      it "should render the new form" do
        expect(response).to render_template("projects/new")
      end
    end
    context "where all is well" do
      before do
        allow(instance).to receive(:save).and_return(true)
        post :create, params_new_instance
      end
      sets_flash(:notice)
      it "redirects to new_deployments_path" do
        expect(controller.controller_path).to eq(new_deployment_path)
      end
    end
  end
```

project controller

```
  def create
    @project=Project.new(params_project)
    if @project.save
      record_saved
      return redirect_to(new_deployment_path(@project))
    else
      check_for_errors
      return render('/projects/new')
    end 
  end
```

why is this failing? am i approaching this in the right way?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `new_deployments_path` instead of `new_deployment_path`
This is my first suggestion. Them can be more but not enough information: `routes.rb` and **deployments controller** for example

Comment: now in block "redirects to new_deployments_path" you need replace `eq(new_deployment_path)` smth. like here: `eq(new_deployment_path(:post))`. Sorry, now my eyes can't be opened more. In my country night now. But I think you understant what I meant. You need variable for correct testing path `new_deployments_path`